# Security evaluation terminology

Tags: audit, threat-modeling

I'm learning about Protection Profiles, Security Targets and Target of Evaluations, and these all seem like very abstract ideas to me. Could someone explain with examples how these work in practice? For example, what does it mean to be implementation independent?

Are these things usually done before or after a system or software is created? What's Common Criteria?

**I don't get the part about how something can be implementation independent yet still be about a specific product? Also is this more focused on an existing IT product, or software development?**

Comment: what book are you studying?

Comment: Is the wiki not doing it for you? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Criteria

Comment: @schroeder it's from lecture slides but also I checked Security Engineering by Anderson. The wiki does help a lot, but still I don't get the part about how something can be implementation independent yet still be about a specific product? Also is this more focused on an existing IT product, or software development?

Comment: I think you need to update your answer with this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Common Criteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Criteria) is an international standard for evaluating the security of a software artifact. Depending on the exact level ([EAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_Assurance_Level)) of CC that is being used, this can include information about processes used during software development as well as testing of some of the security aspects of the software.

Because software systems are so complex, it is not always possible to validate it in entirety. As such, only a portion of a system may be targeted for evaluation. This portion is called the Target of Evaluation or TOE.

CC only provides general guidelines as to what is important to monitor during development and testing. Each type of software product can have specific requirements. [Protection Profiles (PPs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protection_Profile) are an agreed upon set of requirements for a specific type of software and EAL. For example, there could be a PP for a web server for EAL 1, 2, 3, etc... For each EAL, it will specify required features, documentation, and testing that the TOE must meet in order to achieve that EAL.

A [security target (ST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Target) specifies the expected functionality of the application. For example, if you have a web app, it may be expected to meet some or all of the requirements for a web server PP, a database PP, and some product-specific requirements as well.

Comment: Is it mainly for software development or IT?

Comment: Development as far as I know.

Comment: So is this all done before a product is implemented e.g. before programming begins?

Comment: Depends on the E Although plan on making. The lower levels are pretty easy. They require things like an access controlled source code system. Those you can do retroactively, even after an app ships. But higher EALs require more documentation and are better if planned for from the beginning. You need an auditor to get certified, they'll help you through this process.